# How to set up google-diff-match-patch C# library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-diff-match-patch

So I am a newbie and I couldn't find a proper answer to this on the internet.
After digging a little bit here is what I came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download google-diff-match-patch from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/downloads/detail?name=diff_match_patch_20121119.zip)

One you have extracted it, open up your microsoft visual studio project

Go to View->Solution Explorer or press Ctrl+Alt+L

In solution Explorer right click on your project name and go to Add->Existing Item... or press Shift+Alt+A

In the dialog box that appears locate your diff-match-patch folder and go in csharp directory and select **DiffMatchPatch.cs** and click on Add

Then in solution explorer right click on References->Add Reference...

Search for System.Web and add it.

Now come back to your program (in my case Form1.cs) and type

```
using DiffMatchPatch;
```

Now you are ready to use all the [functions](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API) of the diff-match-patch library in your C# program

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, add the Nuget Package DiffMatchPatch and add it to your project.

A Demo Code is as follows :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using DiffMatchPatch;

namespace ConsoleApp_DMPTrial
{
     class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var dmp = DiffMatchPatchModule.Default;

                string file1Content = "";
                string file2Content = "";

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file1.json"))
                {
                    file1Content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file2.json"))
                {
                    file2Content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                var diffs = dmp.DiffMain(file1Content, file2Content);

                dmp.DiffCleanupSemantic(diffs);

                for (int i = 0; i < diffs.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(diffs[i]);
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I was particularly interested in doing a diff in JSON files, hence the Stream Reader is used, otherwise it works on normal strings as well.